# Modificadores de if /I /A en CMD

Tags: cmd, msdos

basicamente lo que dice el titulo, excattamente de que sirve los modificadores /I, /A cuando utilizamos un if? Ej: if /I

Ejemplo, mi profesor al utilizar IF lo hace de la siguiente manera: if /I 5 == 5 (echo Es igual), y mi pregunta viene ¿Que hace exactamente el /I, en que afecta? Lo mismo para el /A

Y si me podrian decir que otros modificadores mas hay para IF lo agradeceria

Comment: Ejemplo, mi profesor al utilizar IF lo hace de la siguiente manera: if /I 5 == 5 (echo Es igual), y mi pregunta viene ¿Que hace exactamente el /I, en que afecta? Lo mismo para el /A

Answer (score 1):

Según la documentación del [`IF`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/if), el uso del `/I` es para establecer una comparación no sensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas. Vale decir, esto `IF /I "A" == "a"` será verdadero cuando esto `IF /I "A" == "a"` no. En el contexto que mencionas, `if /I 5 == 5`, este modificador tiene poco sentido, ya que que estamos haciendo una comparación numérica.

Por otro lado, el parámetro `/A` que comentas, si existe, no está documentado.

Comment: Gracias, pdorias decirme esto? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/287750/opcion-modificar-en-programacion-batch