# Opcion MODIFICAR en programacion BATCH

Tags: cmd, batch, msdos

estoy haciendo un menu basico con las tipicas opciones, Registrar, Eliminar,Modificar y Mostrar Todos, conciste en que el usuario ingresa datos y esos datos que ingresa se guardan en un archivo.txt con el nombre que ingreso.

El caso, ya hice la opcion de registrar y eliminar funcionan correctamente, el tema es en modificar (ya paso codigo) donde si me modifica la letra, pero no me aparece el nombre de la variable, simplemente sale espacio en blanco, código:

```
@echo off
:inicio
echo.
echo MENU PRINCIPAL
echo 1. Alta
echo 2. Baja
echo 3. Modificar
echo 4. Mostrar Todos
echo 0.Salir

set /P op= Ingrese una opcion: 

echo.

if %op% == 1 (GOTO :alta)
if %op% == 2 (GOTO :baja)
if %op% == 3 (GOTO :modificar)
if %op% == 4 (GOTO :mostrarTodos) else (echo Opcion incorrecta
     GOTO :inicio)

:alta 
echo.
set /P nombre= Ingrese un nombre: 
set /P ci= Ingrese la cedula de identidad: 
mkdir Personal
echo Nombre: %nombre% > Personal/%nombre%.txt
echo Cedula: %ci% >> Personal/%nombre%.txt
GOTO :inicio

:modificar
set /P nombre= Ingrese un nombre: 
if exist Personal\%nombre%.txt (
set /p nuevoNombre= Ingrese el nuevo nombre: 
set /P nuevaci= Ingrese la cedula de identidad: 
echo Nombre: %nuevoNombre% > Personal/%nombre%.txt   :: Me sale 'Nombre: ' espacio en blanco
echo Cedula: %nuevaci% >> Personal/%nombre%.txt)
GOTO :inicio
```

En cambio si el código de modificar lo pongo en la etiqueta :alta si me lo modifica correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
:inicio
cls <-------
echo.
echo MENU PRINCIPAL
echo 1. Alta
echo 2. Baja
echo 3. Modificar
echo 4. Mostrar Todos
echo 0.Salir

set /P op= Ingrese una opcion: 

echo.

if %op% == 1 (GOTO :alta)
if %op% == 2 (GOTO :baja)
if %op% == 3 (GOTO :modificar)
if %op% == 4 (GOTO :mostrarTodos) else (echo Opcion incorrecta
     GOTO :inicio)

:alta 
echo.
set /P nombre= Ingrese un nombre: 
set /P ci= Ingrese la cedula de identidad: 
mkdir Personal
echo Nombre: %nombre% > Personal/%nombre%.txt
echo Cedula: %ci% >> Personal/%nombre%.txt
GOTO :inicio

:modificar
cd Personal <-------
set /P nombre= Ingrese un nombre: 
if exist %nombre%.txt (call:modificar_code) <-------
GOTO :inicio

:modificar_code <-------
set /p nuevoNombre= Ingrese el nuevo nombre: 
set /P nuevaci= Ingrese la cedula de identidad: 
ren "%nombre%.txt" "%nuevoNombre%.txt" <-------
echo Nombre: %nuevoNombre% > %nuevoNombre%.txt <-------
echo Cedula: %nuevaci% >> %nuevoNombre%.txt <-------
goto:EOF <-------
```

Con esto ya funcionaría, no puedes meter tantas cosas dentro de un if, tienes que llamar a una función desde el if o redireccionar el código a una etiqueta, además he añadido algunos detalles como limpiar la pantalla cada vez que llegas al menu para que no se repita constantemente y he solucionado un fallo que había al crear el archivo modificado.
Veo que estas empezando con este lenguaje, si tienes cualquier duda no dudes en preguntarme ya que me considero un usuario experto en este lenguaje. (las líneas cambiadas estan marcadas con flechas, quítalas antes de ejecutar el código).